# Combinatorics How Many Tree

Tags: combinatorics

How can I prove that for any tree $G=(V,E)$,
$$
      |E|=|V|-1 
$$
I have tried the induction on the number of vertices but nothing happened.

Comment: Induction on $|V|$ works fine if you’ve already proved that every tree has a vertex of degree $1$.

Comment: can you show me the steps so i can find where did i make a mistake @BrianM.Scott

Comment: If you show us what you have tried, we can help you to improve your solution.

Answer (score 1):

SKETCH: Suppose that it’s true for every tree with $n$ vertices, and let $T$ be a tree with $n+1$ vertices. Let $v$ be any vertex of $T$ with degree $1$. Let $T'=T-v$, the graph obtained by deleting $v$ and the one edge attached to $v$. Clearly $T'$ has $n$ vertices. Check that $T'$ is a tree, and apply the induction hypothesis to conclude that $T'$ has $n-1$ edges. But $T$ has exactly the same edges as $T'$ plus the one edge that was deleted, so $T$ has $n$ edges, as desired.

Comment: Now everything is okeyy thanks

Comment: @SerkanKlvz: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The inductive approach doesn't require that you already know every tree has a vertex of degree one. Consider, instead, induction on the number of edges.

Let $T$ be a tree with $n$ edges, and we want to show that $T$ has $n+1$ vertices. Pick an edge $e \in E$, and delete it (leaving both vertices in), to get $T' = T-e$. Write $v_1, v_2$ for the endpoints of $e$. The resulting graph must have two connected components, namely $C_{v_1}$ and $C_{v_2}$ - if $T'$ were connected, then $T$ would contain a cycle, and if there was any other connected component of $T'$, then $T$ wouldn't have been connected. And, of course, $C_{v_1}$ and $C_{v_2}$ must be trees themselves.

Let $k$ be the number of vertices in $C_{v_1}$ and $k'$ the number of vertices in $C_{v_2}$. Then by the induction hypothesis, $C_{v_1}$ has $k-1$ edges and $C_{v_2}$ has $k'-1$ edges, so $T$ has $(k-1)+(k'-1)+1 = k+k'-1$ edges. Since $k+k'$ is the number of vertices in $T$, the result follows.

Corollary: Every tree has a vertex of degree $1$.

Proof: We use the identity $$2|E| = \sum_{v \in V} \deg(v).$$ Together with the previous result, this gives us $$\sum_{v \in V} \deg(v) = 2|V|-2.$$ If every vertex had degree at least $2$, then the sum would have to be at least $2|V|$.